# How many Me Bf 109 were produced in Czechoslovakia during WW2

Tags: world-war-two, aircraft, czechoslovakia

It is known fact that Czechoslovak factories(or at least Avia) produced Messerschmitt Bf 109 during WW2. After the war ended, they for some time continued production, called Avia S-99 and when engines ran out, Avia created hybrids called S-199, which were used in 1948 by Isreal to fight off airforce of their enemies.

I'd like to learn more about how many of them were produced here during the war, but after quick search, the best I found was confirmation that Avia indeed did produce Bf 109s during the war. Anyone here knows where to look for documents that would give numbers, or at least offer some approximation?

Comment: If you are looking for wartime production (not S-99 , S-199 and Bf-109 completed after the war) , figures will be hard to find. Recently, number of authors started doubting official German production figures as a whole, and dismissed them as propaganda. For example : https://www.slideshare.net/NenadPavlovic12/german-fighter-production-in-ww-two